# Getting error in ad mediation with adcolony and othrs in unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob, adcolony

Showing error in `.addnetworkextrasbundle(AdColonyAdapter.class, AdColonyBundleBuilder.build())`

This is the code which shows error

```
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
    //.AddTestDevice(AdRequest.TestDeviceSimulator)
.addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdColonyAdapter.class, AdColonyBundleBuilder.build())
    //  .AddTestDevice("6A06FD05C6220D9AB87EF2CE09E5BE53")
.AddKeyword("game")
.Build();
```

I'm getting the following error

> parser error:identifier expected,class is a keyword

[image]

Comment: u probably need to use **AddNetworkExtrasBundle** with capital **A**

Comment: @Nika   it's not working. In documentation they specified like these   .addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdColonyAdapter.class, AdColonyBundleBuilder.build())         [link](https://adcolony-www-common.s3.amazonaws.com/pub-adapter/android/AdColonyAdapterIntegrationGuide.pdf)

Comment: ok, remove and re-type **.addNetworkExtrasBundle(** there should appear a pop-up telling you which type of arguments should follow. what does it say?

Comment: @Nika AddExtra,AddKeyword,AddTestDevice these are the arguments.

Comment: oh, mm, no these are functions, argument is a variable that go into the function: **MyFunc(var a)** in this case **a** is an argument to function **MyFunc**. When you type a function name and open the bracket it will suggest the types of the arguments, from that you could guess what you should feed to that function.